# Can not edit EDIMAX EW-7228APn settings in browser

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have an EDIMAX EW-7228APn wireless range extender, and I need to edit some things on it, however I can not seem to connect to it via the IP, I tried the one printed on the bottom, and I tried using nmap to find out what IP it would be under, however I can not get to it in the browser, it just can not establish a connection.

I don't want to reset it until I know I have to.

P.S: I don't have the CD that comes with it

Comment: can you ping it? Are you trying to get to it over wireless or are you plugged directly into it?

Comment: I can ping what I think it's on, and I am directly plugged into it. The pinging seems to take way to long though.

Answer (score 1):

Put your computer on the same network, say an IP of 192.168.2.20, 255.255.255.0 and try again.  After access restore you IP/4 settings.